# Manipulating the code authorisation problem - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create Authentication and Authorisation in a ReactJS application. I got the below snippet from a guide and am concerned about the code

```
isAuthenticated()
 {
   // Token is returned via the server using an API
   const token = this.state.token

  if(token.length > 0)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }

}

render() {

const isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated();
return (
<div>
  {isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to={{pathname: '/map'}}/> : (

   // Else remain on the login page
```

Of course the isAuthenticated method isn't at all finished or secure but has enough to ask the question.

As this file is Javascript and therefore downloaded onto the client, what stops the user from manipulating the code? Example below using Chrome Developer Tools.

[image]

Unless I have the wrong end of the stick, the user can just change anything in the JS and then authorise themselves? So therefore (if I am right), is there a secure way in ReactJS to do Authentication and Authorisation?

Thanks

Comment: Don’t do the equality check in the front end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what stops the user from manipulating the code?

Nothing.

> is there a secure way in ReactJS to do Authentication and Authorisation?

No. Never trust the client. Send the token to the server, validate it there, and only then respond with the secret information.